# Wordpress > Transfer google verification file to root directory on plugin activation/install

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a wordpress plugin which presets several settings in a wordpress site and creates some default pages which are the same for all my sites. I would like to include an html file in my plugin zip package that is placed into the site's root directory "as is" (same file name, etc)

The file is my google verification file, which is the same for all my sites, so I'd like to save a few steps and automate the process of installing it, along with my default setup steps that my plugin handles.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Really? You couldn't google this?

`copy($from, $to)`